Movie about a kidnapped Arabian princess
Saw a movie on tv around 1970-75. A princess is given a box for her birthday (by the Black Prince?) which opens when she is asleep and releases a creature who steals her away. She goes to live with the prince and is bewitched by a mirror in which she sees her own image. Her reflection morphs from her own innocent face into someone more sinister. She is ultimately rescued by a young sailor. I always thought he was Sinbad, but I'm not so sure now.

Sounds like Jack the Giant Killer from 1962. Similarities (from the Wiki synopsis):

the kingdom celebrates the crowning of Princess Elaine... The reception goes well until [evil sorcerer] Pendragon... arrives disguised as a foreign lord. He gives her a magic toy that is actually Cormoran the giant, and which is given to the Princess. When Elaine is asleep, Pendragon uses his magic to make the giant grow to full size and capture Elaine...

And later...

While Jack and Elaine are rejoicing at sea, Pendragon sends his demonic witches to intercept Jack's ship.

And also...

At Pendragon's castle, Pendragon uses his powers once again to turn Elaine from a princess into an attractive, but evil witch... Elaine stands before a mirror, revealing her witch's form, but Jack manages to break free, destroys the spell put on Elaine, and flees with her and his animal friends.

Here's the trailer:




I think you are right, although almost none of this looks familiar.  But that's memory for you. Those monsters look like Ray Harryhausen creations.
